# Reference for packing-covering of the sphere.

Tags: geometry, reference-request, packing-problem

I suspect the following to be true and well known.
I am looking for a reference.

About the notations: $d$ is the dimension, 
$S^{d-1}$ is the unit euclidean sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$,
$d(x,y)$ is the distance between $x$ and $y$.

> There exist constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ depending on $d$ such that for
>   any $n$ we can choose $u_1,\ldots,u_n\in S^{d-1}$ with the following
>   properties:
>
> - $d(u_i,u_j)> c_1 n^{\frac{-1}{(d-1)}}$ (the balls of centers $u_i$  and radius $\frac{c_1}2 n^{\frac{-1}{(d-1)}}$ don't overlap)
> - $\forall u\in S^{d-1}, \min_i d(u,u_i)< c_2 n^{\frac{-1}{(d-1)}}$ (the balls of centers $u_i$  and radius $c_2 n^{\frac{-1}{(d-1)}}$
>     cover the sphere)